How to set a hover state color in a WordPress pattern?
I have a simple WordPress pattern based on the TwentyTwentyFour theme for a footer copyright.
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/patterns/footer.php
I am able to set the footer text color and the color of the link but how do I set the link's hover state text color?
This is the wp:group:
<div id="copyright" class="wp-block-group has-contrast-background-color alignwide" style="padding-top:var(--wp--preset--spacing--half);padding-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--half)">
    <!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","style":{"elements":{"link":{"color":{"text":"var:preset|color|contrast-3"}}}},"textColor":"contrast-4","fontSize":"small"} -->
    <p class="has-text-align-center has-contrast-4-color has-text-color has-link-color has-small-font-size">
    <?php
        $copyright = '&copy; '.date('Y').' All rights reserved. ';
        $copyright_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( __( 'https://example.com', 'textdomain' ) ) . '" rel="nofollow">Link Target</a>';
        echo sprintf(
            esc_html__( '%1$s Web Design by %2$s', 'textdomain' ),
            $copyright, $copyright_link
        );
        ?>
    </p>
    <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

Can this be done with the theme.json file? I don't want to use CSS if it can be done.
Thanks
